# How to remove a built-in Visual Studio Code Color theme

Tags: themes, visual-studio-extensions

I want to remove the color themes from Visual Studio Code which I don't use. For example, I want to remove **Kimbie Dark**, **Monokai**, **Monokai Dimmed** and **Red**.

I referred to a Visual Studio Code document, which you can also read by clicking [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes). But this document didn't help me!

I followed these steps which were written in the document:

1. Press **Ctrl + Shift + X** to open your **Extensions**.
2. On the top, click **Views and More Actions...** (3 dots forming a horizontal line)

According to the Document, there should be an option named **Show Built-in Extensions**. But in my case, it's not there!

**System Information**

**Software:** Visual Studio Code

**Version:** 1.58.2 (The Latest version as of now)

**Channel:** Stable

**Platform:** Windows

**Version:** Windows 10, version 21H1 (The Latest version as of now)

**Edition:** Windows 10 Pro

**OS Build:** 19043.1110

Answer (score 1):

1. open your **Extensions**.
2. On the top right, click  the **3 dots** forming a horizontal line.
3. Input "**@builtin**" in the search box.